# iOS how can I make MapKit display custom indoor map?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, mapkit, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

I'm trying to create a map of the office I'm working at. I have a high resolution image, and would like to autorotate it in the direction the user is heading, allowing the user to navigate around the map. I thought this could be accomplished using CoreMotion/CoreLocation and a UIScrollView, but this seems like there's some work involved.

So I'm wondering if there are easier solutions for combining a custom map and direction/position on that map - can MapKit handle this for me? Are there other frameworks that can help me show a local 2D map with compass orientation on it?

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your high-res image into map tiles easily with [TileMill](http://tilemill.com).

Comment: How i will upload my image into tilemill

Answer (score 2):

You should use some custom tiles with MKTileOverlay which only display at a very high zoom level (like z 18 or whatever).  I suggest you take a look over at NSHipster and read what they have about it:

http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself, came across the NSHipster article while searching for solutions to my own problems.

Comment: I've taken a look at this, and it appears that MKMapView cannot zoom close enough to allow for indoor mapping, even if tiles for this were provided (at most, zoom close enough to have a  building to take up 5% of the screen).

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have any developments? Thanks

Comment: As a workaround, you can change the size of the real indoor environment.
If your building takes just 5% of your screen, resize the coordinates and use the augmented coordinates to recreate a bigger tile set that can works well with zoom in MKMapView