# How to add custom floor plan for MapView with zoom and pan

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am developing an iOS app using swift. I need to show a custom floor plan which users can zoom and pan. Floor plan is an image which I need to set to a mapview instead of showing a world map. When zooming it should load images for particular levels. And also I have to show some pin pointers for some points. I do not want to show the current location.

MKMapView is the best option? Or is there anything else to achieve this?

Comment: You should probably just use a plain UIScrollView.

Comment: If I use scrollview, I have to implement image reload (when zoom and pan) from the scratch

Comment: It depends. Is your map tiled or a single image?  Zoom and pan with a single image is trivial.

Comment: Then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071154/ios-how-can-i-make-mapkit-display-custom-indoor-map

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html) for start. It shows how to position floor plan on map. So you'll require in addition to implement delegates methods - `func mapView(mapView:MKMapView regionDidChangeAnimated animated:Bool)` or `func mapView(mapView:MKMapView regionWillChangeAnimated animated:Bool)` to determine current zoom level to change your image visible part (as soon as it's a tiled image).